# Racket - expected: sequence? given: #<sequence> contract violation

Tags: pattern-matching, scheme, generator, racket

Playing around with generators and pattern matching in racket I run into the following error while practicing lazily destructuring a collection and I can't figure out what the error is nor why it happens.

```
  (require racket/match)
  (require racket/generator)
  (require data/collection)
  (sequence->list
   (in-generator
    (let recur ([seq '(1 2 3)])
      (match seq
        [(sequence) (void)]
        [(sequence next next-rest ...)
         (yield next)
         (recur next-rest)]))))
```

Gives me the following error:

```
sequence->list: contract violation
  expected: sequence?
  given: #<sequence>
  in: the 1st argument of
      (-> sequence? (listof any/c))
  contract from: 
      <pkgs>/collections-lib/data/collection/collection.rkt
  blaming: /var/folders/g4/0st3r3c513n6ymf2nkw11ml40000gn/T/ob-racket-CFPotf
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: <pkgs>/collections-lib/data/collection/collection.rkt:64.3
  context...:
   /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/7.7/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/blame.rkt:347:0: raise-blame-error
   /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/7.7/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/combinator.rkt:324:9
   /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/7.7/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-val-first.rkt:486:18
   "/var/folders/g4/0st3r3c513n6ymf2nkw11ml40000gn/T/ob-racket-CFPotf": [running body]
   temp35_0
   for-loop
   run-module-instance!
   perform-require!
```

Without the generator and if I'm just doing `(cons next (recur next-rest))` everything works fine so it shouldn't have anything to do with my pattern matching code. But then again, I'm pretty confident with generators and have done things like this plenty of times, just without the pattern matching bit. I am pretty sure that this *should* work but have no clue why I'd be getting this error nor even what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the notion of *sequence* from `data/collection` is slightly different from *sequence* in `racket`. The `sequence->list` function from `data/collection` doesn't always work on sequences from `racket` or `racket/generator`, so you'll need to use the `sequence->list` from `racket` instead.

One way to do that, is to avoid importing `sequence->list` from `data/collection`:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require racket/match)
(require racket/generator)
(require (except-in data/collection sequence->list))
(sequence->list
 (in-generator
  (let recur ([seq '(1 2 3)])
    (match seq
      [(sequence) (void)]
      [(sequence next next-rest ...)
       (yield next)
       (recur next-rest)]))))
```

This produces `'(1 2 3)` instead of the error you were getting.

Another way to fix this is to convert the `racket` notion of *sequence* into the `data/collection` version, which is closer to the `racket` notion of *stream*. You can do this with `sequence->stream`.

```lisp
#lang racket
(require racket/match)
(require racket/generator)
(require data/collection)
(sequence->list
 (sequence->stream
  (in-generator
   (let recur ([seq '(1 2 3)])
     (match seq
       [(sequence) (void)]
       [(sequence next next-rest ...)
        (yield next)
        (recur next-rest)])))))
```

This also produces `'(1 2 3)`.

It might seem redundant to have `sequence->list` and `sequence->stream`, but think of it more like `data/collection-sequence->list` and `racket-sequence->data/collection-sequence`.

Although it's kind-of inconvenient to have to carry around 2 different notions of sequence while both are called just "sequence". If you want you can import the `data/collection` stuff with a prefix to mark them as separate, such as `dc:`

```lisp
#lang racket
(require racket/match)
(require racket/generator)
(require (prefix-in dc: data/collection))
(sequence->list
 (in-generator
  (let recur ([seq '(1 2 3)])
    (match seq
      [(dc:sequence) (void)]
      [(dc:sequence next next-rest ...)
       (yield next)
       (recur next-rest)]))))
```

Depending on how the rest of your project looks you might want different things for your style.